# Sunspot-Solr was started and won't attach to database

Tags: solr, sunspot

Background:

Did a switchamaroo to a cluster server from a solo box. As a result, a few things were overwritten in the transfer.

Of them, was that sunspot-solr doesn't read the database anymore.

I know of this command

$> sunspot-solr start -- -p 8982 -d data/solr/development

Which didn't work. If this is the golden command, then possibly I'm gettingt he port or dir wrong on it. If that's the case, where can I find out the port and dir info to reconnect the database to sunspot?

Thanks! And big kudos to out_of_time as well.

Comment: can you access the admin console? e.g. http://localhost:8983/solr/admin

Comment: Yes. Not really sure what to do with this though. And also this is just on my local..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Had to reindex from script/console

Ex:

irb> Object.reindex

=> nil